# Why does this transistor limit the current so much?

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, npn

I have been trying to understand how a transistor works. I bought a simulator to be able to understand it better.

Below is a small circuit I designed. The load is a lamp. The characteristics of the lamp are 5 V, 50 W, so it should draw 10 A.

When I design the schematic without the transistor etc, it does draw 10 A.
However when I use the transistor weather I put on the lamp 50 W or 20 W etc it will not draw a "big" current.

Of course this is a "generic" transistor from the sim.

The sim gives me the following settings to configure the transistor (please check the bottom left of the picture)

I do not understand how to configure this transistor since those settings do not match with the datasheet information at all.

[image]

EDIT:
Without Resistor at all on the base Ib is too high but still Ic is "too low"
[image]

Comment: You need 100mA into base to switch 10A load.     `Ib=Ic/B  ,B=100`  Try Rb = 20ohm.

Comment: That means putting a negligible resistor value to feed the base, eg 1 ohm

Comment: @MichalPodmanický B is the forward beta?

Comment: @Kris Right. In real transistor you probably dont find the one with Beta=100 for such a high Ic current.

Comment: You're using a generic transistor from the simulator, and you say _"... do not match with the datasheet information at all."_. What datasheet are you expecting the generic transistor to conform to?

Comment: In transistor model I see 1ohm emitter + 1ohm collector resistance. With this values you dont reach 10A. Try lower it if its possible.

Comment: How do you calculate that? How could i configure this transistor? Those settings do not seem to be included in the datasheet :/

Comment: 2ohms (C-E) at 10A makes voltage drop 20V. Its even higher than 5V supply can give.

Comment: To clarify, the light bulb in your circuit has resistance 0.5ohm. It makes no sense to waist 7/8 of power on transistor and get the rest 1/8 of power to be effective on bulb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lamp needs 10 A to be fully on.

So your transistor then needs to be able to conduct **at least** 10 A. If the transistor wants to conduct more, that's OK, only 10 A will flow as the lamp will prevent more current from flowing.

So the **collector current** of the NPN transistor needs to be 10 A. All bipolar transistors have a certain amount of **current amplification** which is called \$h_{FE}\$ or \$\beta\$. This \$\beta\$ is the **ratio** between collector and base current:

\$\beta = \frac{I_C}{I_B}\$

When you want a collector current of 10 A then your base current will be about \$\beta\$ times **smaller**. Transistors for small currents (much less than 1 A) often have a \$\beta\$ of around 100. Transistors for large currents usually have a smaller \$\beta\$ of maybe 30 (it depends on the actual transistor).

But you're in a simulator so we can do anything we like. So let's **assume** that \$\beta\$ = 100 that means that your base current would need to be: 10 A / 100 = 100 mA.

I see that your base current is **only** 516 uA so it needs to be about 200x higher!

If you want to be able to switch on/off a 10 A lamp with a small current (smaller than 1 mA) then I would recommend using an N-channel MOSFET. MOSFETs do not need a high current at their input. Do realize that MOSFETs do need a high voltage at their gate, it depends on the MOSFET how much that needs to be. Some MOSFETs can work with the 3.3 V you're using in your schematic.

Comment: I just edited the post. I tried to even remove the base resistor and it draws a lot of current now.. however Ic seems to be still "low"

Comment: @Kris You're now hitting the limitations of the models in your simulator. Applying 3.3 V **directly** to the base-emitter like that will **destroy** such a transistor immediately. I suspect that this transistor model is also **not suited** for switching 10 A. So I suggest that you "scale the currents down", I mean, change the lamp to 5 V, 100 mA and add a base resistor such that around 1 mA is flowing into the base. Then what happens?

Comment: @Kris though I would also use a MOSFET gor this, if you want to stick to BJTs you can look for "Darlington Pairs". It's double BJT configuration with much higher DC gain than a single BJT.

Comment: I am trying to choose a mosfet. I came through this one https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1912111437_UMW-Youtai-Semiconductor-Co-Ltd-SI2308A_C347491.pdf .  How can Id be Absolute Maximum 2A but on the graphs to have Id up to 12A?

Comment: In the maximum ratings there's a *pulsed drain current* which has a maximum of 10 A. The fact that they measured up to 12 A means they're "on the edge" which can work for **short** pulses but there are **no guarantees**. You **CANNOT** use this MOSFET to switch a 10 A lightbulb. I would select a MOSFET that is rated for at least 20 A even for a 10 A bulb. *Why?* Because, when cold, a lightbulb has a **lower resistance** than when it is hot. So when you switch it on, much more than 10 A will flow. That will destroy your MOSFET unless it is properly rated for that.

Comment: The 10 A pulse current is a **really** short pulse, think in the order of less than 100 us. The "cold" current of a lightbulb will last longer than that so you cannot use the "pulsed" rating.